# Cannot import "strings" or "net/http"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have this message:

> ```
> cannot find package "strings" in any of:
>     /Users/alexamil/go/src/strings (from $GOROOT)
>     /Users/alexamil/golang_alex/src/strings (from $GOPATH)
> ```

golang should be installed correctly, and I have:

```
go version go1.8 darwin/amd64
```

GOROOT and GOPATH are both defined as above. I assume "strings" and "net/http" are core libraries, so why cannot go find these libraries given that GOROOT is defined?

Ok so I checked out GOROOT, and it turns out, I don't see "strings" and "net/http", so I guess how the F do I install them? Using Google to find out how to install these things is WAY harder than it needs to be - has nobody written an article on how to do this?

Comment: The std lib is installed together with Go. If you don't have it then it is highly probable that your Go installation didn't go as it should. https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: Don’t set GOROOT. It’s set implicitly in almost every case.

Comment: GOPATH is for source code you create, and is generally $HOME/go. But you used this for GOROOT. GOROOT should be where Go was installed. And Go should _absolutely not_ be installed in the GOPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I unset GOROOT and it worked

`$ unset GOROOT`

I see some userland docs telling people to set that manually, but apparently that's wrong.

Comment: It used to be necessary sometimes, but that was years ago. With modern versions GOROOT isn't necessary anymore (and mostly harmful).

Comment: yeah that's a shame that it changed, but that's how it goes

Comment: @AlexanderMills You can still set GOROOT, but now it's optional. Most people consider this change a benefit, not something that's a shame.